# Setup Nativescript on windows 7

Tags: node.js, nativescript, npm-install

Can some one help me? I'm trying to install NativeScript on my Windows 7, I'm having below errors:

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\nt17127\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "nativescrip t" npm ERR! node v4.4.5 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.2
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property 'emit' of null npm ERR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

- **npm cache clean**
- **npm remove -g nativescript**
- **npm remove -g nativescript** (yes twice)
- **npm install -g nativescript**

Comment: Thank you Nathanael for your quick response. your solution works flawlessly!!! Any Idea how to install nativescript on a machine that have java 8 and android installed? running **@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"**  command will not override my default java and android settings?

Comment: Well in this case you should follow the instructions at http://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win   --  I would type "java -version" if it 1.8 or later, you can skip step 3.   Also since you already have android stuff installed; you can skip the actual install of the base part of android (step 4a) & probably the path statment (step 4b).    Then do step 5.  If step 5 fails; then you do actually need to set the path to the android sdk.

Comment: Thanks Nathanael for your response.